# Mongoid: has_many with the foreign key in an embedded document

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

Is there any easy way to make has_and_belongs_to_many work with foreign keys in embedded models of the other class?

My use case is:

```
class Account
  include Mongoid::Document
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end

class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  embeds_many :memberships
end

class Membership
  include Mongoid::Document
  belongs_to :account, autosave: true
  embedded_in :user
end
```

The idea is that the membership model also includes other data relating to the membership, such as roles.

However, even though in the database a user has multiple foreign keys to accounts (in the embedded memberships), the has_and_belongs_to_many in Account won't pick these users up.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that MongoDB/Mongoid does not support direct access to embedded fields via a relational association.